# How to get Longitude/Latitude from Geography Data in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I need the longitude and latitude of the centre of geography data in PostGIS. The format is called EPSG 2206 and the columns in record are "length","shape_area" and "the_geom"

Comment: Which version of PostGIS are you using?

Answer (score 7):

i use the query to get longitude and latitude.

`Longitude`

```
SELECT ST_X(the_geom) FROM myTable;
```

`Latitude`

```
SELECT ST_Y(the_geom) FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of object is "the geography"? Note that irregular polygons may not have a "center". However, you have 2 options depending on the data type:

1- Centroid:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) from TABLE_NAME;
```

[**Documented here**](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Centroid.html)

2- Point_On_Surface:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom)) from TABLE_NAME;
```

[**Documented here**](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_PointOnSurface.html)

**Edit**:

Note also that the [**documentation**](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) says:

> One restriction is that [the geography type] only supports WGS 84 long lat (SRID:4326).
>   It uses a new data type called geography. None of the GEOS functions
>   support this new type. As a workaround one can convert back and forth
>   between geometry and geography types.

This means that you cannot have data of type geography with EPSG/SRID 2206.

Comment: Both these functions only work on `geometry `, not `geography`. Docs on `geography` are [found here](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography). These can be casted using `the_geog::geometry` to enable the above functions.